# overwrite 2 templates file by custom module, still loading the core files

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, email-templates

I am using Magento 2.4.3p-1

I have 2 files

```
vendor/Aw/Review/view/frontend/templates/email/review/request_form.phtml
vendor/Aw/Review/view/frontend/email/review_reminder.html
```

Since those 2 files in Magento core folder, I cannot just directly modify here.

I did create 2 patches and they works fine.

However, I have more need to make changes, that's why I try to use create custom module method to do the override

```
app/code/Aw/Review/view/frontend/templates/email/review/request_form.phtml
app/code/Aw/Review/view/frontend/email/review_reminder.html
```

After I enable this custom module.

```
Aw_Review
```

It didn't show the change I made.

I did ran below comments, still not get the change effected. I did some debug, looks like the still running the core codes.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Please advise what I miss or where I should check. Can anyone tell me what exactly file I need to build this custom module?

Thankyou very much

Comment: You need to place these files on your theme or if you want to do using a module then you need to set the template in layout & set the email template in email_templates.xml

Answer (score 1):

You should override core phtml files in theme dir.